# Error trying to install Berkeley DB

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, berkeley-db

I downloaded Berkeley DB 2.5.16 xml for windows.
I try to get it built on VS 2008, however it fails each and every file. How can i prevent it?

Errors:

```
-- Skipped Build: Project: dbxml_unit_runner, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
2>------ Build started: Project: XercesLib, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: db, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>Compiling...
2>Compiling...
2>cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'Wp64' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
2>XIncludeUtils.cpp
3>aes_method.c
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>XIncludeLocation.cpp
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>XIncludeDOMDocumentProcessor.cpp
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>XSDElementNSImpl.cpp
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>DOMXPathResultImpl.cpp
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>DOMXPathNSResolverImpl.cpp
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>DOMXPathExpressionImpl.cpp
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>DOMTypeInfoImpl.cpp
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>DOMTreeWalkerImpl.cpp
3>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\db-4.8.26\dbinc/win_db.h(45) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
3>bt_compact.c
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>DOMTextImpl.cpp
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>DOMStringPool.cpp
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>DOMStringListImpl.cpp
3>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\db-4.8.26\dbinc/win_db.h(45) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
3>bt_compare.c
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>DOMRangeImpl.cpp
2>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\xerces-c-src\src\xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp(44) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
2>DOMProcessingInstructionImpl.cpp
3>c:\dbxml-2.5.16\db-4.8.26\dbinc/win_db.h(45) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
```

Please help me out as im new to VS and BERKLEY DB

Comment: Are you sure it's possible (and intended) to compile this in a windows environment?

Comment: There's an entirely different file that has specific instructions for windows.. so yeah